# Using Biber with latexmk

Tags: miktex, latexmk, biber

With version 4.22, [latexmk](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) claims to

> [s]upport the use of biber (with the biblatex package) as an alternative to bibtex for generating bibliographies, with automatic determination of whether to use bibtex or biber.

I decided to give it a go. I'm using Windows 7, Strawberry Perl, MiKTeX 2.8 (including latexmk 4.22b), Biber 0.7.3 (registered in the PATH environment variable) and TeXworks r.670 (which includes settings for latexmk). Result: While latexmk generally seemed to work fine, it always called BibTeX as bibliography backend even when the preamble of my LaTeX file embodied `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`. (In contrast, Biber works fine under texify, the MikTeX equivalent to latexmk.) At first, I thought that I had missed something obvious (I'm still open for the possibility), but then I looked at `latexmk.pl`. Here are code lines 4204--4207:

```
    my $bib_program = 'bibtex';
    if ( exists $generated_log{"$bbl_base.bcf"} ) {
        $bib_program = 'biber';
}
```

So Biber should be called if some condition involving a bcf-file (biblatex/Biber control file) is satisfied. In a copy of `latexmk.pl` in my local texmf tree, I replaced the above code with a test for the existence (or so I think) of said bcf-file:

```
    my $bib_program = 'bibtex';
    if ( -e "$bbl_base.bcf" ) {
        $bib_program = 'biber';
}
```

Result: The modified latexmk correctly determines when to use Biber instead of BibTeX. (When switching from Biber to BibTeX, remnant bcf-files must be deleted manually.)

So: Have I discovered a bug in latexmk 4.22b or have I missed something obvious involving my system/TeX distribution/editor?

EDIT: To make my question more focussed: I'm interested to hear if other users of latexmk observe the same behaviour (latexmk never calling Biber). If so, I'd be happy if someone suggested a solution that -- unlike my "quick fix" -- doesn't involve redundant Biber runs.

EDIT 2: Herbert pointed out that Perl may behave differently in Windows vs. Linux. I will report my observations to the author of latexmk after the end of the bounty period; I'm still interested in reports from other users.

Comment: what does `$generated_log{..}` really do?

Comment: @Herbert: According to code lines 3024--3025 (comment): "%generated_log: keys give set of files written by (pdf)latex (e.g., aux, idx) as determined by \openout = ... lines in log file." This function (?) is use three times in `latexmk.pl`.

Comment: @lockstep: With your solution biber is called everytime, which doesn't really make sense, when nothing changed in the *.bcf file. I thought that `$generated_log{..}` could do this job to controll changes or not in the bcf file. But from your description it does nothing special, the reason why your -e should do the better job. But this is only a guess, a closer look into the code is needed.

Comment: @Herbert: I should stress that I have absolutely no clue with regards to perl (I only found out about `-e` by trial and error), so my "description" what `$generated_log` does may be a comment snippet not relevant for the question at hand.

Comment: @lockstep did you run it with the `-diagnostics` option to see if there is a path problem somewhere?

Comment: @Yannis: I tried `latexkm -diagnostics biblatextest` (`biblatextest` being the name of my test file) from the command line and spotted nothing extraordinary (except bibtex being called no matter what). Again: biber works with my modified latexmk.pl as well as with texify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Note: This update from January 25th, 2011 was moved to a separate answer.*

It turned out that the problem child wasn't Windows, but MiKTeX. Quoting John Collins, the author of latexmk:

> A log file produced by MikTeX is
>   missing some information compared with
>   a log file from TeXLive.  The missing
>   lines are of the form
>
> ```
>  \openout...
> ```
>
> that latexmk was using to deduce the
>   names of file written by (pdf)latex.

A new version of latexmk (4.22c) that makes the detection of the use of Biber compatible with MikTeX is available at http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/latexmk/versions.html.

Comment: The current version of latexmk on CTAN is 4.30a, so that should work, too. Btw, the "official" capitalization of _latexmk_ (or at least the one John Collins uses) seems to be like a regular noun, i.e. all lower-case unless it's at the beginning of a sentence.

Answer (score 9):

`exists $generated_log{"$bbl_base.bcf"}` does a test if the list of files `%generated_log` includes an entry for "$bbl_base.bcf". From my point of view such an entry is missing in the list `%generated_log`, the reason why the call fails. If you test it with -e which does in general the same, it works in fact of the now missing check of `%generated_log`. You should report it to the author. It could also be possible that some of the Perl functions have not the same behaviour as with Linux.