# How to make LaTeXmk work with XeLaTeX and biber

Tags: xetex, biblatex, latexmk, biber

I'm trying to make `latexmk` works with XeLaTeX and biber for my thesis. The document will have many cross references. What settings do I need to ensure it works correctly? My current settings for `latexmk` are below.

```
-e 
$pdflatex=q/pdflatex -synctex=1 %O %S/
-pdf
$fullname
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Put

```
$pdflatex=q/xelatex -synctex=1 %O %S/
```

in the `.latexmkrc` file.

For Biber, look at [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8950). However the latest version of `latexmk` coming with TeX Live 2011 works with Biber, choosing it automatically when needed (thanks to PLK for pointing this out).

Comment: The latest version of latexmk which comes with TexLive 2011 works fine with biber.

Comment: @PLK: I'll change my answer, thanks for remarking.

Answer (score 78):

LatexMk (since [4.31](http://users.phys.psu.edu/%7Ecollins/software/latexmk-jcc/versions.html)) supports the *-xelatex* option and auto-detects biber.

Therefore, in the fabulous world of 2015:

```
$ latexmk -xelatex biberedtexfile.tex
```

This is [equivalent to](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/latexmk/latexmk.1.en.html#xelatex):

```
$ latexmk -pdfxe -dvi- -ps- biberedtexfile.tex
```

Or to putting the following into `.latexmkrc`:

```
$pdf_mode = 5;
$dvi_mode = 0;
$postscript_mode = 0;
```

Comment: If you want this in your `.latexmkrc` file:

    $pdflatex = "xelatex %O %S";                           
    $pdf_mode = 1;                                                        
    $dvi_mode = $postscript_mode = 0;  

This is what `latexmk` does when it encounters the `-xelatex` flag.

Comment: @rubdos while that works, that is *not* correct. The `-xelatex` flag corresponds to setting `$pdf_mode = 5; $dvi_mode = $postscript_mode = 0;`. No need to override `$pdflatex`.

Comment: I think it is `latexmk --xelatex biberedtexfile.tex` that works.

Comment: Make sure you **do not include the `-pdf` option** — this negates the `-xelatex` option

Answer (score 5):

This is a really old question, but I still want to help those who are here.

Besides `-xelatex` option metioned by @Tommy, latexmk's [doc](http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8/software/latexmk/latexmk-461.pdf) explains `$pdf_mode`'s usage:

> If equal to 5, generate a pdf version (and an xdv version) of the document using `xelatex`, using the commands specified by the `$xelatex` and `xdvipdfmx` variables.

Thus, setting `$pdf_mode = 5` in `.latexmkrc` would help.

Answer (score 2):

If neither of the two other approaches works (as in my case), put this in `.latexmkrc`, as suggested by @rubdos in the comments:

```
$pdflatex = "xelatex %O %S";
$pdf_mode = 1;
$dvi_mode = 0;
$postscript_mode = 0;
```