# Generate ToC in XeTeX with single build

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex

To use ToC in a pdf using XeTeX compiler I have to compile document twice to get correct table of content and page number.
According to an article about [Table of contents](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Table_of_contents) one can get a appropriate result in single build by adding `-pdf` option on `latexmk`.

> Note: For the table of contents to work properly you must compile the document twice or use latexmk -pdf

but unfortunately I can't find equivalent option for XeTeX.

Comment: Welcome to the site! See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231351/586: use `latexmk -xelatex filename.tex`.

Comment: Hi Torbjornt, That seems to solve the problem. Thanks. BTW why don't you post that as a answer?

Comment: Well,  I'd rather we close this as a duplicate of the other, if you don't mind.

Comment: sure, do as you please