# Disable ISSN but keep ISBN with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing a document where I want `ISBN`s to be shown for books so I have turned on the `isbn` option. This causes the `ISSN` for journals to be shown when I reference an article. Is there a way to enable `ISBN`s but dissable `ISSN`s? They seem to be controlled by the same option in when referring to the `biblatex` manual. I'm also using the `biblatex-chem` styles as well if that helps.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can clear the contents of the `issn` field. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32930) gives you two options:

1. Invoke `\clearfield{issn}` in `\AtEveryBibitem` (and maybe `\AtEveryCitekey`).
2. Set the `issn` field to null with `biber`'s source mapping feature.

Here's an example for the first approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-rsc,isbn=true]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issn}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{issn}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Periodical{jcg,
  title = {Computers and Graphics},
  issuetitle = {Semantic {3D} Media and Content},
  volume = {35},
  number = {4},
  year = {2011},
  issn = {0097-8493}}
@Article{sarfraz,
  author = {M. Sarfraz and M. F. A. Razzak},
  title = {Technical section: {An} algorithm for automatic capturing of the font outlines},
  journal = {Computers and Graphics},
  volume = {26},
  number = {5},
  pages = {795--804},
  year = {2002},
  issn = {0097-8493}}
@Manual{cms,
  label = {CMS},
  title = {The Chicago Manual of Style},
  subtitle = {The Essential Guide for Writers, Editors, and Publishers},
  edition = {15},
  publisher = {University of Chicago Press},
  location = {Chicago, Ill.},
  date = {2003},
  isbn = {0-226-10403-6}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{jcg,sarfraz,cms}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could suppress the `issn` field more selectively. For example

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{article}{\clearfield{issn}}{}}
```

would print `issn` for `@periodical` entries in the bibliography.

In the second approach, source mapping can be done two ways:

- `\DeclareSourcemap` in the document preamble. This feature was introduced in `biblatex 2.0` / `biber 1.0`.
- The `sourcemap` option in the `biber.conf` file. The configuration file overrides any source mapping done in the preamble.

To demonstrate `\DeclareSourcemap` we use the same document, but with the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-rsc,isbn=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
       \step[fieldset=issn, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
...
```

This source mapping will suppress `issn` only in `@article` entries. To omit `issn` in all entry types, remove `\pertype{article}`.

The following `biber` configuration file will carry out the same source mapping:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <per_type>ARTICLE</per_type>
        <map_step map_field_set="ISSN" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

Here we can remove `<per_type>ARTICLE</per_type>` to suppress `issn` in all entry types. Save this file as `biber.conf` in the same folder as the document.

In either source mapping method, suppose the document is saved as `test.tex`. At the command line you would invoke:

```
latex test
biber test
latex test
```

Further details on source mapping can be found in `biber`'s manual. For additional `\DeclareSourcemap` examples, refer to the `biblatex` manual.

Comment: Thanks Audrey. I've tried the \AtEveryBibitem{\ifentrytype{article}{\clearfield{issn}}{}}
 method so far and it works nicely. With regards the command line bit of the second suggestion would latexmk do that automatically?

Comment: @Darling Sorry, I don't have any experience with `latexmk`. But this topic has been discussed previously in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8950).

Comment: Yes, the `latexmk` tool will do this automaically, since it involves no special command line switches o biber. Then again, neither solution des.