# Disable month in biblatex bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, datetime

Currently my bibliography items are printed like this:

> R. B. Griffiths, Nonanalytic Behavior Above the Critical Point in a Random Ising
>   Ferromagnet, Physical Review Letters 23 (July 1969), pp. 17–19 (cit. on p. 10).

which took quite some time to fiddle with a custom bibliography style in biblatex. The remaining issue is the month field. Instead of `(July 1969)` it should just print `(1969)`. I have read every bit of the biblatex documentation concerning dates and there are hundreds of options but not once is there a possibility mentioned how to completely disable the month.

Do I have to dig down even further into biblatex or is there an easy or documented way to change the default behaviour?

Comment: Do you use the `date` field? If you do so why don't you use the `year` field?

Comment: I took the recommendation and based my style on the closest style, `authoryear.bbx` and `standard.bbx`. In there `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}` uses `\usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}`, which uses `\usebibmacro{issue+date}`, which uses `\usebibmacro{date}`. So I guess I am using the date field. Changing that to `\usebibmacro{year}` does not work, as this macro does not seem to exist.

Comment: No, I mean in your `.bib` file.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40097/disable-issn-but-keep-isbn-with-biblatex

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32930/is-it-possible-to-suppress-a-specific-field-from-bibtex-bbl-in-biblatex

Comment: @Thorsten: I am using Zotero and Jabref to manage the `.bib` file, both use the `year` and the `month` field.

Comment: @Alexander, JabRef uses every field you tell it to. Besides, there is also a biblatex mode in JabRef which supports the date field out of the box.

Comment: @Alexander So why don't you just leave the `month` field empty?

Comment: @domwass, @Thorsten: The imported `.bib` from Zotero has both, year and month already populated. I was not aware of the biblatex mode in Jabref, but that does not seem to help in my situation either. If `date` contains `2009` and the field `month` is populated biblatex prints `Oct. 2009`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could add one or both of the following commands to your preamble:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{month}}
```

Answer (score 79):

The `biblatex` package option `date=year` should also work.

Comment: IMHO this is a nicer solution that to delete the `month`. One may also need `labeldate=year` as well; or `alldates=year` and then something like `urldate=short`.

Comment: Thank you for the update, this function has been added to biblatex in version 2.8 (in 2013). So if you are using any newer version this is the best option and allows even further configuration than just deleting the month.