# How to print only year (no day/month) with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I would like to have Biblatex print **only the year** of a publication in the bibliography. Currently it shows the year, month and day.

The "date" option (e.g. date=iso8601) can't do that.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: But the situation is really nothing special. Biblatex ALWAYS prints the full date (if provided) in the bibliography. This is not an error or something. I think a MWE is rather elaborate here, since citations are involved...

Comment: Maybe `date=iso8601` can't do it, but `date=year` seems to work fine for me. That option might be relatively new.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In analogy to [Disable month in biblatex bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55780/18674) you can just disable the `month` and `day` fields with the commands

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}}
```

For a short moment there came to my mind that there could be a caveat with the `urldate` field that declares when a URL has been checked, but `biblatex` even takes care of this. The `urldate` is still printed as full date. Compare the MWE and its output below:

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@BOOK{test,
author= {A. Author},
title = {A Title for a Book},
date = {2012-10-08}
},
@ONLINE{test2,
author = {A. Author},
title = {Some title},
url = {http://example.com},
urldate = {2013-01-08}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you intend to do? If not, please provide a MWE to work with.

Comment: Perfect! I was not aware of a "\clearfield" command. Thank you so much! (Also, you proved me wrong on the 'elaborate' MWE!)

Comment: The basic idea behind the MWE is to be only as elaborate as necessary. In many cases (I have to admit, not here) one finds the source of the problem by oneself or can at least limit it to a much smaller amount of code which makes it easier to ask the right question then.

Comment: This solution creates a problem for me, where some references (which have a non-empty month field in the .bib file) have their month replaced by the Issue number (or maybe just whatever the previous field is).

Comment: @level1807 Are you sure that it is caused by this solution? Can you prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and post it as a new question -- maybe referring to this one?

Answer (score 13):

The [question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55780) @benedikt-bauer linked to has since been updated with a new answer which contains a nicer solution:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346281/181287

> The `biblatex` package option `date=year` should also work.
>
> One may also need `labeldate=year` as well; or `alldates=year` and then something like `urldate=short`

Which should be valid for biblatex version 2.8 (2013) and higher.

---

**Updates:**
For clarity, here are the relevant (shortened) parts of the manual:

> `date=year,short,long,terse,comp,ymd,iso` `default:comp`
> This option controls the basic format of printed date specifications.
>
> `<datetype>date=year,short,long,terse,comp,ymd,iso` `default:comp`
> Similar to thedateoption but controls the format of the `<datetype>date` field in the datamodel.
>
> `alldates=year,short,long,terse,comp,iso`
> Sets the option for all dates in the datamodel to the same value. The date fields in the default data model are `date`, `origdate`, `eventdate` and `urldate`.

Full manual with more details and explanations of the possible options can be found here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf

Comment: this doesn't work for clearing the day, though.

Comment: What do you mean by 'clearing'? It sets the date format to print only the year (in the output), regardless of whether there is also month and day data available. It doesn't 'clear' anything.

Comment: Yes. By "cleaning" I mean that it discards the day and, hence, only prints the year and month.

Comment: Correct, there is no standard date format to print only year and month. But the question was "_How to print only year (no day/month)_".

Comment: @FrederickNord If you set the date format to `year` you should only see the year, the day and month should not be shown. If that is not the case for you, I suggest you ask a new question with a full example document that shows what you are doing and how it doesn't work for you (MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: @WillemDuncan I think it would make sense to remove the last passage about `labeldate` having been renamed to `labeldateparts`. The situation is a bit complicated. And for a while now `labeldate` is the correct option for this job. What is now the option `labeldateparts` used to be called `labeldate` once. Back then an equivalent to `labeldate` (as it is now) did not exists. When such an option was implemented, the old option needed to be renamed for consistency with other `...date` options. ...

Comment: ... So yes, technically `labeldate` was renamed to `labeldateparts`. But that was the old `labeldate`, not the one you use and explain in the question.

Comment: Thanks, have updated the answer. It confused me a little as well, seeing as I found no easy reference to it in the manual.