# How to remove month from bibliography using biber?

Tags: biblatex, biber

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable month in biblatex bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55780/disable-month-in-biblatex-bibliography)
>   [How to print only year (no day/month) with Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89842/how-to-print-only-year-no-day-month-with-biblatex)

I use *(Author Year)* as citation style and want to create a bibliography with *Author (Year): Title*.

However when I use the following command, I get *Author (Year, Month)* in my bibliography:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,isbn=false,dashed=true]{biblatex}
```

How can I make biber generate the bibliography style I want, i.e. withouth the months (and maybe even days)?

Comment: `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}`. (I guess this question has been answered before.)

Comment: Also related (remove month and day field): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89842/how-to-print-only-year-no-day-month-with-biblatex/

Comment: Alright, both links help! Can be closed as related/duplicate.