# Suppress page numbers in in-text citations but one-time only

Tags: biblatex, citing, package-options

My advisor requires page number in in-text citations, consider the following MWE and its output:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
  @article{einstein,
      author =       "Albert Einstein",
      year =         "1905"
  }
  @article{shakespeare,
      author =       "Shakespeare",
      year =         "1603"
  }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
  \bibliography{references}

\begin{document}
  Hello! \parencites[893]{einstein}[79]{shakespeare}
\end{document}
```

**Currently:**
[image: Citations with page numbers]

**My question:**
Is there an option or some way to get a PDF such that no page numbers appear in the result? Removing them from the actual source code would be destructive and also a rather large effort.

**Desired result:**
[image: Desired citation without page number]
But without actually changing my `\textcite` and `\parencite` commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I completely agree with your advisor that page numbers in citations are a good things. So unless there are very good reasons to remove them, I would not do that.

That said, here is a fairly simple method that removes prenotes and postnotes from all citation commands using the standard `\AtEveryCitekey`-`\clearfield` trick (cf. [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864), [Disable ISSN but keep ISBN with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40097/35864), [Disable month in biblatex bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55780/35864;) normally I prefer other methods over `\clearfield`, see e.g. [How to omit address field while using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491887/35864), but here `\clearfield` is the only method of those that works, since `postnote` and `prenote` are virtual fields).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \clearfield{prenote}%
  \clearfield{postnote}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[379]{sigfridsson}

ipsum \autocites[380]{sigfridsson}[24]{nussbaum}{geer}[21]{worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998)]

Comment: I was on the lookout for a simple solution like this. And it works amazingly, thank you. I agree that page numbers can be incredibly useful when reviewing, it's just that I prefer having an easy option to turn them on and off. Feels like it could almost be a normal option available during `\usepackage{biblatex}`.

Answer (score 1):

Store the old `\parencite` and redefine it to ignore any optional arguments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{einstein,
  author = {Albert Einstein},
  year   = {1905}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\NewCommandCopy\oldparencite\parencite% Copy \parencite into \oldparencite
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\parencite}{o m}{\oldparencite{#2}}

\begin{document}

Hello! \parencite[893]{einstein}

\end{document}
```

The above requires an up-to-date LaTeX (post Oct 2020). If you don't have that, add [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse) or use

```
\let\oldparencite\parencite% Copy \parencite into \oldparencite
\renewcommand{\parencite}[2][]{\oldparencite{#2}}
```

---

A more general approach would be to tap into the inner workings of [`biblatex`](//ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

```latex
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\blx@cite@parencite}[4]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@citeinit
  \mkbibparens{%
    \blxciteicmd{parencite}{#1}{}{#3}{}%
  }#4%
  \endgroup
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\blx@cite@textcite}[4]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@citeinit
    \blxciteicmd{textcite}{#1}{}{#3}{}%
  \endgroup
}
\patchcmd{\blx@multicite@add}{#2}{}
\makeatother
```

The above commands update `\parencite`, `\parencites`, `\textcite`, and `\textcites` to ignore their second arguments - the optional argument.

Comment: This seems to work well. Can you elaborate on the meaning of ```o m```? How would I proceed with redefining ```\parencites[56]{article1}[768]{book2}[9]{paper3}```?  
I can follow your alternative code (with `\let` and `\renewcommand`), however I reckon this problem becomes much more difficult with `\parencites` taking a variable amount of parameters

Comment: @taihao: Correct. My solution just works with `\parencite`, not `\parencites`. `o` and `m` refer to `o`ptional and `m`andatory argument within the [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse) syntax, so `o m` is similar to `[2][]` when using `\newcommand`. I guess a better approach might be to tap into the [`biblatex`](//ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) internals and ignore the optional argument rather than to circumvent it the way I do.

Comment: @taihao: I've added something to the bottom of my answer. Please review whether it suits your needs regarding `\parencite` and `\parencites`.

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you. I will update my question to reflect this usecase.