# globally switch off page numbers in citations?

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing a manuscript and one of my supervisors wants citations with pagenumbers, the other not. Is there a way to globally turn them off? I tried it using AI, but \parencites is not working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
sorting = nyt,
style = authoryear,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{addentum.bib}
@book{texbook,
    author = {Donald E. Knuth},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The {\TeX} Book},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional}
}

@book{latex:companion,
    author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Gossens
        and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle
        and Chris Rowley},
    year = {2004},
    title = {The {\LaTeX} Companion},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
    edition = {2}
}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{addentum.bib}

% Redefine the \cite command without the optional page number argument
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[2][]{\oldcite{#2}}

% Redefine the \parencite command without the optional page number argument
\let\oldparencite\parencite
\renewcommand{\parencite}[2][]{\oldparencite{#2}}

%% Redefine the \parencites command without the optional page number argument
%\let\oldparencites\parencites
%\renewcommand{\parencites}[2][]{\oldparencites{#2}}

\begin{document}
    
    \cite[5]{texbook}
    
    \parencite[122]{latex:companion,}
    
    \parencites[see][123]{texbook}
    
    \parencites[122]{texbook}[122]{latex:companion,}
        
        
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

These works for `\cite` and `\parencite`, but `\parencites` works only sometimes and not in this minimum working example. Even if it works, it only suppresses the page from the first source and not the other 6.
So, I'm puzzled: Maybe it's because I might not find the right words to search this topic, but I expected this is an straightforward question :-)
Maybe someone can provide an elegant solution for this? Like a block of code I could just uncomment to show page numbers and vice versa?

Thank you all ahead!

Comment: Did you try this solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/584565/42803 ?

Comment: ...works perfectly. Thank you very much Andrey!