# Clean .bbl files with latexmk -C

Tags: biber, latexmk

I use TeXLive 2012 and compile with run

```
latexmk -pvc -pdf -quiet test.tex
```

later I clean the directory with

```
latexmk -C
```

But `test.bbl` remains. How can I help latexmk to find bbl files?

#### test.bbl (first lines)

```
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 2.1 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber as required.
%
```

Comment: You *need* the `.bbl` file for typesetting the document!

Comment: ...I thought latexmk creates it. I never wrote a .bbl file manually.

Comment: If your document is in final form and you don't need to compile it any more, then you can safely delete the `.bbl` file.

Comment: as long I do not delete it manually with `rm` latexmk ignores changes I made with jabref.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default, `latexmk` treats `.bbl` files as non-regeneratable.  This is because the `.bib` from which they are made is not always available.  See the documentation for a fuller explanation, especially the explanation of the `$bibtex_use` variable.  To get `latexmk -C` to delete `.bbl` files, put the following in an initialization file:

```
$bibtex_use = 2;
```

Comment: Oh my, you were faster than me by 10 seconds. `:)` In other news, I know that this is probably not the best place to say this, but your awesome work with `latexmk` inspired me to write `arara`. I really admire all the effort you've put into the tool. Thanks a million.

Comment: Is `$bibtex_use = 2;` equivalent to `-bibtex`?

Comment: Yes.  The option `-bibtex` simply sets `$bibtex_use` to 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what do you mean by " initialization file", the `makefile`?

Answer (score 20):

Another option to the presumably canonical answer John gave is specifying `$clean_ext` in a latexmkrc file, which contains your personalized global options. This file can be in one of the places I outlined in [my answer to 
Latexmk: makeglossaries, Biber and pdfLaTeX / Where to put latexmkrc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41149/4012). Also see the [latexmk manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/latexmk).

My complete list of extensions looks like this:

```perl
$clean_ext = 'synctex.gz synctex.gz(busy) run.xml tex.bak bbl bcf fdb_latexmk run tdo %R-blx.bib'
```

(As a result of -- I think -- SyncTeX, latexmk, Texmaker, `biblatex`, Biber, `todonotes`)

Comment: Just to clarify, in some situations (like, if your .bib file is in a search path, not the current dir, and latexmk doesn't find it), latexmk may sometimes not delete the bbl file even if you have put `bbl` in the `$clean_ext` string in .latexmkrc.  That is, you'd need to use Johns answer from above to make it clean out bbl files. I think this is explained in the [the latexmk docs](https://manpages.org/latexmk); see `-bibtex-cond`.

Answer (score 2):

Reading from the [documentation](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf):

> **-bibtex-cond1**
>
> ... .bbl files are only treated as precious if one or more bibfiles fails to exist.

Thus you simply do:

```bash
latexmk -bibtex-cond1 -C
```