# Redirecting *.aux, *.log files, with a command in the tex file

Tags: compiling, auxiliary-files, sourcecode

Is there a latex command that can be included in a file compiled with pdflatex that can direct the *.aux, *.log files resulting from the compilation process, to a specific folder ?

I have seen several posts on this question in stack-exchange however *all of them have solutions which involve making changes in the latex front-end used*. I repeat, I am looking for a command that we can just include in the tex file.

The reason for doing this is that I wish to collaboratively edit tex files with another person over dropbox. We may be using different editors or operating systems even. So, I want the change to be made on the tex file that accomplishes the task of redirecting of *.aux, *.log files to a specific folder.

Comment: perhaps using `arara` with something like `% arara: pdflatex: {options: "--output-directory=/path/to/output/directory/"}`

Comment: The reasoning doesn't seem to support the need. What's wrong with leaving the auxiliary files in the location where the `.tex` is located?

Comment: It makes the folder containing the tex file look messy. I am sorry if this reasoning isn't good enough, but I thought if I can manage to move the aux files to another location, we can easily locate the tex files in a folder.

Comment: IMO _only_: Separating any `.synctex.gz` `.aux` and `.log`..etc files from `.tex` folder is not a good idea since we need them for any debugging/synctex interaction for future needs. If they are really messy clean them after compilation using automation tools like [`latexmk`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83341/clean-bbl-files-with-latexmk-c). Redirection in `.tex` file can only be done by [`arara`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/arara/doc/arara-usermanual.pdf) like @cmhughes mentioned. May be you just drop/share your `.tex` only in dropbox and leave rest with you.

Comment: in `github` you can configure `.gitignore` to contain `*.aux` etc; does `Dropbox` have something similar?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152843/finding-latex-output-files#comment348887_152843

Comment: @PavithranIyer if you move the aux files you have to configure bibtex, makeindex, biber, and TeX to find them, it really isn't worth it:-)

Comment: Just make the auxiliary files invisible, e.g. `SetFile -a V *.aux` on OS X.

Comment: May be useful [Is there a way to configure pdflatex to make all but the .tex and .pdf files hidden files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87818)