# Auxiliary files in other directory than .tex file

Tags: compiling, texstudio

I want to make one global folder for all auxiliary files which are produced while compiling `.tex` file (i.e. `.aux`, `.log`, `.out`, `.toc`, `synctex.gz`). I use TeXstudio and I found that I have to change compiling options in `Configure TeXstudio > Commands`. Now I have

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -aux-directory="C:\Latex_Aux_Global" %.tex
```

for PdfLaTeX, which moves all files except `.synctex.gz` file. It is possible to move this file to the same directory as all auxiliary files?

My second problem is that I need to use also BibTex and MakeIndex connected with this global folder `Latex_Aux_Global`. For BibTex I have following command

```
bibtex.exe "C:\Latex_Aux_Global"/% -include-directory="C:\Latex_Aux_Global".
```

I don't know in what way I can make such command for MakeIndex. When I use

```
makeindex.exe "C:\LaTeX_Aux_Global"/%.idx
```

to MakeIndex, while compiling I get error `Can't create output index file C:\LaTeX_Aux_Global/document.ind.` I will be gratefull for any suggestions.

Comment: My advice is really not to do this.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162780/redirecting-aux-log-files-with-a-command-in-the-tex-file?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment373158_162780

Answer (score 3):

Moving the synctex file to another folder will essentially make it useless - you could just as well compile without synctex.

However there is [`ltx2any`](https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any) which

- keeps your directory clean by keeping all files in a folder of your choice
- does a few clever things with the synctex file to allow you to still use it with

  ```
  ltx2any -synctex filename
  ```
- also works with `bibtex` and probably `makeindex` (but I did not test the later)