# How to assign a new folder path for makeindex in Texstudio?

Tags: texstudio, imakeidx, makeindex

I have already set a new folder called `_build` for separating and including the generated aux and bib files of pdflatex and bibtex in Texstudio (with Miktex) as follows:
Texstudio --> Options --> Configure Texstudio --> Commands:

`pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --aux-directory=_build %.tex`

`bibtex.exe _build/% -include-directory=_build`

The above configuration works fine and the PDF is output as desired.

However when I tried to do the same with makeindex (using `\usepackage{imakeidx}` and `\makeindex` in the preamble, and `\printindex` in the body document) and then I changed the configuration of makeindex in Texstudio commands as follows:
Texstudio --> Options --> Configure Texstudio --> Commands:

`makeindex.exe _build/%.idx -include-directory=_build`

Although I see the `myfile.idx` created in the `_build` folder but the Index is not created in the document and I receive this message:

`Input index file myfile.idx not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]`

Is there a way to include the new folder path `_build` correctly in the makeindex command?

Comment: A work around can be copying the created myfile.idx from the `_build` folder and pasting it in the root folder (next to myfile.tex) and then recompile. The index would then print fine. But that's not what I want. I'd rather, if possible, to follow a similar configuration  as I did to `pdflatex.exe` and `bibtex.exe` and apply it to `makeindex.exe`.

Comment: I am sure many will correctly point out that you should "always" run the miscellany of commands and files in ONE folder with the .tex even if that is a subfolder of main There are so many interacting packages that depend on the relative same location without redirecting unless by means of env variables (e.g. you can store all bib related files together using bibinput variable) AFAIK there is no one specific for makeindex although MiKTeX has one for redirecting build folders. **Back to your need**  {imakeidx} hooks makeindex so could try like \makeindex[options=-o ./_build]  so **read manuals**

Comment: this may help https://nwalsh.com/tex/texhelp/mkidx-2.html OR in TeXstudio change makeindex.exe %.idx to something like makeindex.exe -o ./build/%.idx  however I have to let you play with those -i  -o options as I'm otherwise tied up

Comment: @KJO Thx. Tried all the above suggestion with all possible combinations, nothing seems to do the trick! Still stuck at `Input index file myfile.idx not found.` message.

Comment: Similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420573/auxiliary-files-in-other-directory-than-tex-file makeindex is  the most difficult to reassign (though may not be impossible if you get syntax right for your mix of system and editor see samcarters suggestion for a ltx2any helper BUT it requires yet another dependency of RUBY and you've got enough potential issues without yet another , interfering app, personally would run makeindex  in same folder as .tex then script final postprocessing   helper macro/user command via shortcuts to flush the files down to subfolder after last pdfTeX run

Comment: @KJO Well for now I may settle with the "work around" described above or perhaps roll back to the default settings of pdflatex.exe and bibtex.exe without reassigning `_build` folder altogether as I see makeindex looks pretty difficult to reassign  as you said and "enough potential issues without yet another."

Answer (score 2):

This is possible and certainly works from the command line (However as described **certainly not advised** for all cases)
Here is a composed image of the folders during runtime

[image]

The files on the right are in the subfolder "build", which is created by the first PdfLaTeX run (however if you have a bib or other support file you need to make the folder to put it/them in first) whilst the central file group is in folder book_2. Note the "(busy)" file flashes on/off whilst building & disappears once the run is done.

There were many attempts to resolve issues I encountered with TeXstudio running the following series of console commands. and have come to the conclusion that TeXstudio is OK for the first compile and makeindex plus the biber run BUT output from Texstudio produced wrong result on the final pdfLaTeX and although my template suggested an  additional run, only on one occasion did it work and whatever I did even deleting the build folder it would run past the desired result thus destroying the final bibliography structure !!

**What did work** was running from the command line, so I have to presume TeXstudio adds too much poke, anyway here are the commands  I ran

Note -s StyleInd.ist was a requirement of my test files (not normally required)

```
pdflatex.exe  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory ./build/ main
makeindex.exe ./build/main.idx  -s ./build/StyleInd.ist
biber.exe ./build/main
pdflatex.exe  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory ./build/ main
```

And inside TeXstudio they are (**without** my -s ./build/StyleInd.ist)

```
pdflatex.exe  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory ./build/ %.tex

bibtex.exe ./build/%

makeindex.exe ./build/%.idx
```

Comment: Let me try that before I give you my feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. I used your proposed commands `makeindex.exe ./build/%.idx` from within Texstudio/options/commands, and still the index file `*.idx` cannot be found by makeindex. Unfortunately, running from the command line is not an option for me as it seems not handy enough while continuously editing and compiling the main document.

Comment: ODD did you add the altered prior line for pdfLaTeX -output-directory ./build/ with a space before %.tex (you can watch with  explorer that it creates that subfolder NOT a folder called main.tex which was one issue kept tripping me up :-) BEST copy  existing pdflatex to a new profile so default not corrupted, but I don't readilly know how to in TeXstudio so just modified the default command Other editors allow easier linking of new build steps but in your case **need** one dedicated pdflatex run before makeindex, hence the issues with so many ways editors  can be mis-configured.