# bibtex doesn't work when using subfolder

Tags: bibtex

I use texstudio on mac. I changed my configuration so the auxiliary files will be saved in a subfolder. Everything works except bibtex. I get the following message:

Error: Could not start the command: bibtex.exe build/"myfile" -include-directory=build

I copied this line from a previous answer, and tried many other options, but none of them worked.

Attached  pictures of my [commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXmKg.png) and [build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBEHk.png) settings. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `.exe` and try `bibtex build/% -include-directory=build`. On Mac OS executables usually don't have the `.exe` file extension. `.exe` is a Windows thing.

Comment: You will be repeatedly advised by long time epert users this is NOT a good Idea I did show how it MAY work for some cases BUT I  strongly advise against it see problems that can arise https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472061/170109

Comment: That's the reason why I never use such build folders. You can spent a long time to get all tools working correctly ...

Comment: still get the same error: Error: Could not start the command: bibtex build/"labor_networks_literature" -include-directory=build

Comment: That said, I *think* `-include-directory` might be MikTeX-specific and thefore not available if you are using TeX live or MacTeX (MikTeX only recently made its entry onto Unix OSes). I firmly believe, however, that these 'build' subfolders create more issues than they solve and would recommend against using them.

Comment: check which files are currently in which folders the .aux must be in the same folder as the other related support files only the .tex should be in the top folder bibtex sometimes needs the aux filename thus `bibtex  ./build/%.aux`

Comment: ok, I see a consensus here that I should not use the build folder stuff :) Thanks for your feedback everybody!

Comment: Much Much easier to write a script to assign to a shortcut that moves all files and a copy of the pdf(keep) and synctex(keep) down to a new folder at the end, acts a backup for comparison of files if really really needed

Comment: @KJO "... see problems that can arise." Can't agree more! But still can't resist the temptation of having a cleaner working folder, specially for large projects with lots of included files and chapters, as each would generate its own aux, and you may end up having hundreds of them.

Comment: @hesham apart from keeping .tex bib synctex and pdf in the same "MasterBuild" folder (that can have a \include /pictures subfolder I see little reason to not simply keep in one place and use the Purge / Clean auxiliaries (in the most basic TeXworks its called Remove Aux files) command (as found in most editors) once happy with the results

Comment: @Muly If your motivation to use a build folder was to keep your directory clean, have a look at https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any

Comment: "Remove Aux files" I got it in Texstudio too, but wouldn't it slow the recompile?