# Auxiliary files in subdirectory using TeXShop

Tags: texshop, auxiliary-files

Using `TeXShop`, I'd like to create a script that lets me specify the extensions (e.g. `.aux`, `.log` ecc..) whose corresponding files should be put in a separate directory.

I frequently have 20+ files in the folder of the project I'm currently working on, ~15 of which are auxiliary files, and I'd like to find a way to tidy things up. Is this possible to do?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162780/redirecting-aux-log-files-with-a-command-in-the-tex-file?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment373158_162780

Comment: The folder I use for testing examples on this site currently has  2474 log files, occasionally I delete them, but why do they cause problems? As explained at the link above you can configure tex to write aux files to a subdirectory, although personally I don't recommend it, it complicates all other processing.

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7265/35864. Questions on this site indicate that the idea of a 'build' subdirectory is attractive to some, but ultimately causes more issues than it is worth. Auxiliary programs like BibTeX/Biber,  `makeindex` and friends need to be (re)configured to know about the build folder since they won't find the necessary files otherwise. If you stick to a clean folder set-up with one project per directory, the number of aux files is usually acceptable (even though the ratio of aux to input files may be skewed towards the aux files).