# Unexpected citation behavior: biblatex with biber and authoryear

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

The citation style `authoryear-comp` is designed to output citations of the form '(Doe, 1992)'. (See p. 62 of the [`biblatex` documentation](ftp://www.ctan.org/ctan/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).) This has worked as expected for me, even when using Biber as backend.

Recently, however, the behavior of `authoryear-comp` with `biblatex` does not match this. Instead of outputting citations of the form (Doe, 1992), it is simply printing the *title* and the year of the corresponding entry.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},  
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

This paper is very good: \cite{Bli74}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And the generated pdf:

[image: Output using biber and authoryear-comp]

Again, if I don't call Biber, `biblatex` behaves as expected given the citation style.

I'm using pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011), and `biblatex` v1.7. I get the same results using XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (TeX Live 2011).

Thoughts?

Comment: It doesn't happen to me: I get "Blinder 1974"

Comment: Odd. Any thoughts on what could be triggering this?

Comment: Works for me as expected. Is your Biber version up-to-date (0.9.8)? Do you use a `biblatex.cfg` configuration file? Note: The citation looks as if the `author` field had been cleared.

Comment: Yes, my Biber version is up-to-date. (I've reinstalled it using the TeX Live Utility multiple times now.) The citation does look as if the `author` field had been cleared, but I don't know why. The author appears in the bibliography, and it appears in the citation when I don't use Biber.

Comment: @lockstep, I forgot to answer your second question. I don't use a `biblatex.cfg` configuration file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you're compiling the document using the `backend=biber` option setting, but with a bbl file generated by bibtex. biber outputs a dedicated `\name` for `labelname`. It won't find this `\name` from bibtex output, so the fallback `title` field is printed instead. You need to run latex *and* biber when switching from the bibtex backend. Similarly you should run bibtex when switching from biber.

Here are the `\name` elements for your entry from biber:

```
\entry{Bli74}{article}{}
  \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
    {{uniquename=0,hash=8a4ba46206eec0a36340f92bf9ee4f86}{Blinder}{B\bibinitperiod}{Alan\bibnamedelima S.}{A\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim S\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
  }
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{uniquename=0,hash=8a4ba46206eec0a36340f92bf9ee4f86}{Blinder}{B\bibinitperiod}{Alan\bibnamedelima S.}{A\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim S\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
  }
...
```

Compare this with the output from bibtex:

```
\entry{Bli74}{article}{}
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{}%
     {Blinder}{B.}%
     {Alan~S.}{A.~S.}%
     {}{}%
     {}{}}%
  }
...
```

Comment: Excellent! Could this be a problem with `latexmk.pl`? That's what I use instead of manually running latex and bibtex or biber. I ran biber manually and this fixed the problem. Thanks again, Audrey.

Comment: @apc Sorry, I don't use latexmk. You might find [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8950/4483) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me when I switched the citation style from `alphabetic` to `authoryear`.
I resolved it by "reseting" files generated during compilation (i.e. deleting all files that are not`*.tex` - especially `*.bbl` and `*.bcf` ones).

Comment: Wow thanks, I had the same problem with `authoryear` and this works! :)