# MikTeX update caused compilation problems (Oct 2013)

Tags: biblatex, errors, packages, miktex

I just updated all my MikTeX packages in an attempt to deal with the problem posed in this question: [Biblatex citation and bibliography misbehaving in Texmaker - help!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139129/biblatex-citation-and-bibliography-misbehaving-in-texmaker-help). Now TeXworks and TeXmaker both will not compile even the simplest of example documents. I am using biblatex and biber for bibliographies, the problems I am having with which are what has led me down this path.

The test .tex file is

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{biblatex} 
\bibliography{refs} 
\begin{document} 
Hello\cite{KandR}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

The .bib file is

```
@BOOK
  {KandR,
   AUTHOR  = "Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.",
   TITLE   = "{The C Programming Language Second Edition}",
   PUBLISHER = "Prentice-Hall, Inc.",
   YEAR = 1988
  }
```

The logfile for this simple .tex file is:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.10.16) 16 OCT 2013 17:37
entering extended mode
**test.tex
("C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Study\University of Salford\Coursework\MSc project wo
rk\Dissertation files\LaTeX\Tests\test.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty"
Package: biblatex DATE vVERSION programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex2.sty"
Package: biblatex2 DATE vVERSION programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count87
)
\etb@tempcnta=\count88
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds) That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds) that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds) In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.sty"
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count89
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.def"
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2006/04/12 ver 3.3 Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count90
\c@listtotal=\count91
\c@listcount=\count92
\c@liststart=\count93
\c@liststop=\count94
\c@citecount=\count95
\c@citetotal=\count96
\c@multicitecount=\count97
\c@multicitetotal=\count98
\c@instcount=\count99
\c@maxnames=\count100
\c@minnames=\count101
\c@maxitems=\count102
\c@minitems=\count103
\c@citecounter=\count104
\c@savedcitecounter=\count105
\c@uniquelist=\count106
\c@uniquename=\count107
\c@refsection=\count108
\c@refsegment=\count109
\c@maxextratitle=\count110
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count111
\c@maxextrayear=\count112
\c@maxextraalpha=\count113
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count114
\c@highnamepenalty=\count115
\c@lownamepenalty=\count116
\c@maxparens=\count117
\c@parenlevel=\count118
\blx@tempcnta=\count119
\blx@tempcntb=\count120
\blx@tempcntc=\count121
\blx@maxsection=\count122
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count123
\blx@notetype=\count124
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count125
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count126
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count127
\labelnumberwidth=\skip43
\labelalphawidth=\skip44
\shorthandwidth=\skip45
\biblabelsep=\skip46
\bibitemsep=\skip47
\bibnamesep=\skip48
\bibinitsep=\skip49
\bibparsep=\skip50
\bibhang=\skip51
\blx@bcfin=\read1
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\c@mincomprange=\count128
\c@maxcomprange=\count129
\c@mincompwidth=\count130
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-dm.def")
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count131
\c@savedafterword=\count132
\c@annotator=\count133
\c@savedannotator=\count134
\c@author=\count135
\c@savedauthor=\count136
\c@bookauthor=\count137
\c@savedbookauthor=\count138
\c@commentator=\count139
\c@savedcommentator=\count140
\c@editor=\count141
\c@savededitor=\count142
\c@editora=\count143
\c@savededitora=\count144
\c@editorb=\count145
\c@savededitorb=\count146
\c@editorc=\count147
\c@savededitorc=\count148
\c@foreword=\count149
\c@savedforeword=\count150
\c@holder=\count151
\c@savedholder=\count152
\c@introduction=\count153
\c@savedintroduction=\count154
\c@namea=\count155
\c@savednamea=\count156
\c@nameb=\count157
\c@savednameb=\count158
\c@namec=\count159
\c@savednamec=\count160
\c@shortauthor=\count161
\c@savedshortauthor=\count162
\c@shorteditor=\count163
\c@savedshorteditor=\count164
\c@translator=\count165
\c@savedtranslator=\count166
\c@labelname=\count167
\c@savedlabelname=\count168
\c@institution=\count169
\c@savedinstitution=\count170
\c@lista=\count171
\c@savedlista=\count172
\c@listb=\count173
\c@savedlistb=\count174
\c@listc=\count175
\c@savedlistc=\count176
\c@listd=\count177
\c@savedlistd=\count178
\c@liste=\count179
\c@savedliste=\count180
\c@listf=\count181
\c@savedlistf=\count182
\c@location=\count183
\c@savedlocation=\count184
\c@organization=\count185
\c@savedorganization=\count186
\c@origlocation=\count187
\c@savedoriglocation=\count188
\c@origpublisher=\count189
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count190
\c@publisher=\count191
\c@savedpublisher=\count192
\c@language=\count193
\c@savedlanguage=\count194
\c@pageref=\count195
\c@savedpageref=\count196
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-compat.def"
File: blx-compat.def DATE vVERSION biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.def"
File: biblatex.def
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count197
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count198
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count199
\c@smartand=\count200
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\numeric.bbx"
File: numeric.bbx DATE vVERSION biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\standard.bbx"
File: standard.bbx DATE vVERSION biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count201
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count202
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.cbx' found.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx\numeric.cbx"
File: numeric.cbx DATE vVERSION biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
! LaTeX Error: \iffinalcitedelim undefined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.7 \renewcommand*{\iffinalcitedelim}
{%
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.cfg"
File: biblatex.cfg
))
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
D
l.87
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
D
l.87
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
D
l.87
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.87
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 87, version
`' of package biblatex2,
but only version
`DATE vVERSION programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)'
is available.
)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
D
l.3 \bibliography
{refs}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
D
l.3 \bibliography
{refs}
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
D
l.3 \bibliography
{refs}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.3 \bibliography
{refs}
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 3, version
`' of package biblatex,
but only version
`DATE vVERSION programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)'
is available.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\english.lbx"
File: english.lbx DATE vVERSION biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
! Package keyval Error: langczech undefined.
See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.482 }
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! Package keyval Error: langpolish undefined.
See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.482 }
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! Package keyval Error: fromczech undefined.
See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.482 }
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! Package keyval Error: frompolish undefined.
See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.482 }
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
)
\@quotelevel=\count203
\@quotereset=\count204
("C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Study\University of Salford\Coursework\MSc project wo
rk\Dissertation files\LaTeX\Tests\test.aux")
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
Package biblatex Info: No input encoding detected.
(biblatex) Assuming 'ascii'.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex) Assuming data encoding 'ascii'.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'test.bbl' found.
("C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Study\University of Salford\Coursework\MSc project wo
rk\Dissertation files\LaTeX\Tests\test.bbl")
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 4.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 4.
[1
{C:/Users/Mike/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
("C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Study\University of Salford\Coursework\MSc project wo
rk\Dissertation files\LaTeX\Tests\test.aux")
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex) test
(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'test.run.xml'.
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
5681 strings out of 493921
98414 string characters out of 3144878
472965 words of memory out of 3000000
8970 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
4591 words of font info for 17 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
44i,4n,49p,813b,792s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb>
<C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:
/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 41663 bytes).
PDF statistics:
18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

The more complex .tex file which is the file I really need to compile can be seen at the question linked at the top of the page. The errors from this are similar:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read againD l.87

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum. <to be read againD l.87 I was
expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't. ! Missing number, treated
as zero. <to be read againD l.87

! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read againD l.87 A number
should have been here; I inserted `0'.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX
Companion for explanation. Type H <returnfor immediate help. ...
l.87

! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read againD l.14
\addbibresource {References/references.bib}

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum. <to be read againD l.14
\addbibresource {References/references.bib} I was expecting to see
`<', `=', or `>'. Didn't. ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be
read againD l.14 \addbibresource {References/references.bib} A
number should have been here; I inserted `0'.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX
Companion for explanation. Type H <returnfor immediate help. ...
l.14 \addbibresource {References/references.bib}

! Package keyval Error: langczech undefined. See the keyval package
documentation for explanation. Type H <returnfor immediate help. ...
l.482 }

! Package keyval Error: langpolish undefined. See the keyval package
documentation for explanation. Type H <returnfor immediate help. ...
l.482 }

! Package keyval Error: fromczech undefined. See the keyval package
documentation for explanation. Type H <returnfor immediate help. ...
l.482 }

! Package keyval Error: frompolish undefined. See the keyval package
documentation for explanation. Type H <returnfor immediate help. ...
l.482 }
```

Any suggestions as to what could have gone so wrong?

Comment: Your MWE [compiles well without errors](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vP69h.png) with `pdflatex` `biber` `pdflatex` `pdflatex` compilation sequence and option `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}` since we have to tell `biber` engine will be used.

Comment: have a look at [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/15717). i used texlive to run your example.

Comment: Show the complete log file and not only a snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've added the full log file for the very simple example, as requested.

Comment: @texenthusiast I did have a look at that page prior to running the update, but the only thing I took away from it really was that I needed to run in admin mode as well (which I did), and sync prior to updating, which happens anyway when I select a repository. Apologies if I'm missing something?

Comment: PS. The last bit about FNDB + formats is over my head.

Comment: The `numeric.cbx` file seems suspicious. Please, try upgrading `biblatex` to the most recent version with MiKTeX's package manager.

Comment: Your biblatex looks wrong. Where you have "biblatex DATE vVERSION programmable" I have a real date and version: "biblatex2 2013/07/15 v2.7a programmable". And I just run an miktex update so it is not a version problem. It looks as if the some lines at the start of the file is missing or commented. I suggest to deinstall biblatex and to reinstall.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer BINGO. Also seems to have sorted out the citation issue I linked to at the top! Amazing, thankyou! If you would like to post again as an answer and I'll mark it resolved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your biblatex looks wrong. Where you have "biblatex DATE vVERSION programmable" I have a real date and version: "biblatex2 2013/07/15 v2.7a programmable". And I just run an miktex update so it is not a version problem. It looks as if some lines at the start of the file(s) are either missing or have been commented (e.g. by a missing end-of-line char). Perhaps it happend during the installation.

I suggest to deinstall biblatex and to reinstall.