# numeric citation with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

My problem is the following:
I would like to have a numeric citation style; similar to the one in common papers, so in such a way that the citation is printed in form of a number as [1]. I use `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sortcites, sorting=nty, backref, natbib, hyperref]{biblatex}` and `\cite{}` for citations, but still I get an Author-year-style citation...
What could be wrong there?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sortcites,sorting=nty,backref,natbib,hyperref]{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}


\begin{document}
This theory fails to describe the phenomenon of superconductivity.\cite{PhysRev.108.1175}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\printbibliography[title=References]
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as the information you gave us goes, the behavior is unexpected, so there's probably something else you are not telling us. Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)/[(MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Please follow the link provided above. A MWE should be a short but complete piece of code that illustrates the problem, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. You can edit your question to include it.

Comment: For example: ´This theory fails to describe the phenomenon of superconductivity.\autocite{PhysRev.108.1175}´ which gives "This theory fails to describe the phenomenon of superconductivity.[PhysRev.108.1175]". What I would like to get is "This theory fails to describe the phenomenon of superconductivity. [1]" where the number (in this case 1) should be the number of the (sorted) bibliography-entry...

Comment: As described [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266277/134641), this could be a result of not deleting intermediate files during compilation, if you switched from an author-year style. You may want to double-check that you are actually compiling from scratch.

Comment: You still did not provide a MWE... But I assume [Question mark instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/) might help you.

Comment: Thanks for providing a MWE. It still needs the `bib` file and associated `\addbibresource` call, however, to be complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `bib` file contains the [available BibTeX](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.108.1175), the MWE you provided does indeed result in a numeric citation ("[1]").

Please compare your own code with this example (rendered on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pgzpktpgdcrh)).

You may also want to ensure that you have removed any intermediate files and are compiling from scratch.

Comment: Now it worked, thanks! I had to remove the intermediate files!