# How to (re)run Biber on the file

Tags: biber

I got this message "Please (re)run Biber on the file: output and rerun LaTeX afterwards." and I don't know how to rerun Biber. Sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: What is your editor?

Answer (score 16):

`biber` is an external program which you can run

- at the command prompt (in a terminal window), typing the command `biber documentname`
- or within your editor, if your LaTeX editor provides it.

To clarify, if your document is `documentname.tex`, you run `biber documentname`, leaving out the `.tex` suffix. Assuming your cited articles, books, etc. are defined in `sources.bib`, you'd include those sources in `documentname.tex` like this:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{sources.bib}
```

An editor explanation with a lot of screenshots is here, in German: [Wie verwende ich biber in meinem Editor](https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1909/wie-verwende-ich-biber-in-meinem-editor). Luckily, there are a lot of screenshots, so perhaps you don't even need to use Google Translate to translate it.

But you can tell us your editor, and I can update this answer.

Comment: The English version of the German instructions are in [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: If you cite articles, is it recommended to (re)run Biber every time before compiling? Because I created a script to compile LaTeX directly from Vim, so my default command is "pdlatex <filename.tex>". This probably should be "biber filename && pdflatex <filename.tex>". Am I right?

Comment: @Unix perhaps use latexmk: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8950 but yes, rerun if you made a change in bibliography entries.

Answer (score 5):

In TeXstudio it is

```
Tools -> Befehle -> biber (German version)

Tools -> Commands -> biber (English version)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just in case somebody sees this question.

I got the same problem with my project on overleaf. I just cleared the catche files with the little trash can next to "other logs and files", and it worked :).

Comment: Thank you, you saved my time and helped me . it actually worked, you may not know me, but be sure that I LOVE YOU 

Answer (score 0):

Run with command line:

```
biber main # if main.tex is your latex file.
```

biber may not be installed in your system. You can install biber in this way:

```
pacman -S biber # arch linux
apt install biber # ubuntu
```

If you are using macos or windows, biber shall be installed when you installed you latex distribution. If biber is not installed, it is **not** recommended to install biber manually as it may cause conflicts with you TeX distribution. The easiest method is probably just delete all auxiliary file and recompile.

Comment: Welcome! `brew` isn't the standard way to install TeX on Macs. Moreover, it will cause havoc if the TeX distribution already installed is not provided by homebrew because Biber **must** be in sync with Biblatex version-wise.