# Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Hi I'm trying to compile a project with `pdflatex` and am getting some errors with the bib

```
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 145.

[3] (./main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

I'm a bit confused with this message since I've had no problems compiling projects with bibs in the past and recently trying to recompile old projects I get the same error. I tested the [project on overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tmknqrzhswyp) and it compiles just fine.

I don't get why I now need Biber what's wrong with biblatex?

This is a related discussion but I didn't find it helpful.
[How to (re)run Biber on the file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261595/how-to-rerun-biber-on-the-file)

Comment: that looks like the expected messages for a first run. You need to run latex then biber then latex again. (overleaf does that for you)

Comment: Perhaps your editor is set up to run `bibtex`. Change the settings to run `biber` instead. (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations)

Comment: okay im just compiling in the terminal, do I have to install biber? Why has this worked in the past without it?

Comment: latex has never sorted a bibliography (ignoring amsrefs package for now)  it has always relied on an external program  (bibtex originally, or if using biblatex then biber) to be run after latex to sort the entries, after which you run latex again. If it was working before you must have been running bibtex or biber.  You should have biber in your standard miktex or texlive already.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using MacTex (BasicTeX) any idea where I can locate biber

Comment: So I just downloaded biber from here (https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/) put it in `/usr/local/bin` and ran `pdflatex main` `biber main` `pdflatex main`.

Comment: You don't need to install `biber`, it is already in your TeX distribution, like MiKTeX or TeX Live.

Comment: As David Carlisle says: With `biblatex` you always needed to run either Biber or BibTeX on your document. There is definitely no recent change there. (There was a change a few years back that made Biber the default choice over BibTeX, but that really was a while ago.) This is explained in more detail in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. As CarLaTeX says: Never install Biber manually. It is either already included in your distribution or can easily be installed with `tlmgr`/TeX Live Utility/MikTeX Console.